# Get client details in laravel from axios request

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I'm building a piece of analytics code in my Laravel 8 project and need to store some data about a client's browser for reporting purposes. I've got several columns in my database and thus build PHP variable containing all of the data.

I'm using methods on the `$request` object but am finding that this is just picking up the server's details instead of the customer browser's data from the axios request, for example:

```php
$request->path() // this gives me `api/analytics' which is my endpoint, but I'm looking for the webpage URL I'm on, e.g: `window.locatioin.href` for example
```

Another example would be the ip, I'm using:

```php
$request->ip() // gives me something like 2400:cb00:373:1024::ac46:a2d1 instead of the customer's ipv4 address from their browser.
```

How would I be able to modify this, I'll attach my front-end axios request and the function that handles that incoming request:

#### Client side axios request

```js
const res = await app.$axios.post(`${app.$config.apiUrl}/api/analytics`, {
  type: 1,
  affiliate: 'blah,
  campaign: ='blah
}, {
  timeout: 30 * 1000
})
```

#### Laravel function handling the request

```php
/**
 * Handle the incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'type' => 'required|numeric|in:2,3,4',
        'affiliate' => 'required|string',
        'campaign' => 'nullable',
        'additional' => 'nullable'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "One or more fields has been missed or is invalid.",
            'errors' => $validator->messages()
        ], 400);
    }

    try {
        $analytic = [
            'user_id' => null,
            'brand_id' => null,
            'uuid' => null,
            'type' => $request->input('type'),
            'affiliate' => $request->input('affiliate'),
            'brand' => null, // will attempt to set in Microservice
            'campaign' => $request->input('campaign') ?? null,
            'host' => $request->getHost() ?? 'unknown',
            'method' => $request->method() ?? 'unknown',
            'path' => $request->path() ?? 'unknown',
            'ip' => $request->ip() ?? 'unknown',
            'user_agent' => $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT') ?? 'unknown',
            'fingerprint' => $request->fingerprint() ?? null,
            'additional' => $request->input('additional') ?? null,
            'session_date' => Carbon::now()
        ];

        // we don't need to instantly process this job, so let's delay it
        // for a short period of time to further speed up this function.
        $delay = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(15);
        AnalyticWatcher::dispatch($analytic)->delay($delay)->onQueue('analytics');

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Analytic has been dispatched successfully"
        ], 201);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $e->getMessage() ?? "Unable to dispatch analytic"
        ], 400);
    }
}
```

Would `$request` in the context of sending data from client-side to server-side only be the server ip / page name etc?

Comment: `2400:cb00:373:1024::ac46:a2d1` looks like an IPv6 address. Is this your server's address? Or is it in fact the client's IPv6 address? Does your PHP server have anything in front of it like a reverse proxy or load balancer? in that case you'd get the IP of that server instead of the client's, because the PHP server can only detect the IP of the location the request was last forwarded from.

Comment: As for the path, well yes PHP can only see the path/URL of the current request. It cannot see the URL of a web page where that request came from. It cannot even know for sure whether the request actually came from a browser, or from some other HTTP client. You might be able to see that info _if_ the browser sends an Origin header with the request, otherwise you'd have to get your axios code to include it as an extra parameter in the request explicitly.